# IE8 facebook app "Navigation to the webpage was canceled"

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

On IE8, when I go to my facebook page I get the below warning. If I hit "No" everything works, but if I hit yes I get "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" (see 2nd SS). From what I understand the warning is unavoidable in IE8, but I have seen other apps that still load okay after hitting "Yes". For example Candy crush: (https://apps.facebook.com/candycrush/?fb_source=search&ref=ts&fref=ts)

Anyone know how to resolve the "...webpage was canceled" issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your page is on https (as required by Facebook), but you're using an iframe to load content from an insecure location (http). By clicking yes, you've effectively blocked any non-secure asset from loading on that page, including the target of that iframe (resulting in the canceled message).

So all you have to do is

```
<iframe src="https://domain.com/yourpage.php"></iframe>
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, we are not using iframes but I believe I have tracked the issue down to the Page Tab being misconfigured (or lacking the Secure Page Tab URL). Waiting for the client to update their Page Tab settings to see if that resolves the issue. Thank you for your answer as this led me down the right path.

Comment: a better way would be to put *//domain.com/yourpage.php*. This way it will fill the http or https in itself.